# Redmine::activities I would like to display the notifications in the activities for the changes made in the project table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

**Redmine::activities**

I would like to display notifications in the activities for the changes made in the project table. How can I do that?

As I am new to the rails and redmine I would like to have an explanation on how will the activities could get into the list?